# Проверка строки по шаблону в JavaScript

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Если есть шаблон строки, состоящей из ограниченного квадратными скобками набора слов, разделенных точкой с запятой (где one, two, three - это любые слова)

```
var sample = "[ one; two; three ]";
```

то как проверить строку на соответствие этому шаблону, используя регулярные выражения?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Например, так:

```
function isValid(sample) {
    var regexp = /^\[[ ]*[^ ;]+(;[ ]*[^ ;]+)*[ ]*\]$/;        
    return regexp.test(sample);
}
```

- `^\[` - открывающая квадратная скобка в начале строки;
- `[ ]*` - произвольное количество пробелов;
- `[^ ;]+` - один или более символ, отличный от пробела и точки с запятой;
- `(;[ ]*[^ ;]+)*` - произвольное количество последовательностей из точки с запятой, нуля и более пробелов, одного и более символов;
- `[ ]*` - произвольное количество пробелов;
- `^\[$` - закрывающая квадратная скобка в конце строки;

Comment: Я бы заменил [ ] на [\s], так понятнее потом будет. А в целом wow прав для данного случая.

Comment: @EmptyMan, он поделил всю регулярку на части, поэтому повторяющаяся строка нужна.